# Regular expression get numbers after a specific string (ignore newline operators)

Tags: regex

I am currently trying to extract reference numbers from a string using a regular expression. Unfortunately, all my attempts have failed so far and I hope someone can help me here how to get out the numbers which follow "Ref 1:" and "Ref 2:". Here is my current attempt:
https://regex101.com/r/zHOYCg/1

String:

```
ERROR\tERROR\tERROR\t\n
Ref 1:\n
4376113053884\n
Ref 2:\n
8013\t\n
```

Can someone help my?

Comment: Like https://regex101.com/r/zHOYCg/2

Comment: Show the code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? `?<=` means 'preceded by'.

```
(?<=Ref \d:\\n\n)\d+
```